# GLMM - % Veg Cover Summing to 100% with categorical and other continuous data

Tags: binary-data, glmm

I am trying to find the best and simplest (easy for me to understand) analysis for my habitat selection data.  I have used/available data (binary response variable), fixed effects (aspect, slope, %rock, %litter, %shrub), and random effects (grouped by individual).  I have eight veg cover % variables, not all included in the previous sentence, that sum to 100%.  I have been trying to use `glmmadmb`.  Prior to running the model, should I somehow be tying the vegetation cover % variables together with 100% total column so that it is being read as a whole, aside from aspect and slope?  This is how my model looks at the moment.

```
  fit<-glmmadmb(response ~ aspect + slope + rock + litter + etc 
        (1|groupID/spID), data=trans, zeroInflation=TRUE, family="binomial")
```